# Graphic is disposed Exception

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting the following exception stack trace when I open the ADT/Eclipse:

> org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Graphic is disposed...(remaining trace here is quite long)

The corresponding messages in the Event details dialog are as follows:

> Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event
>   [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/UIElement/toBeRendered/SET] to
>   handler
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler@7f6e8e26
>
> Error while loading editor
>
> Unhandled event loop exception

Just prior to these errors I was copying XML files form one project to another.
I have subsequently deleted every XML that had been copied but still getting the errors.

Am new to the ADT have read around a bit have not found any solutions.

Also, this is the first message to appear when opening ADT:

> System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to
>   local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This
>   value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

Comment: Version Control System to the rescue. Can you reset to a valid state, sounds like the appropriate action as without the details of your project this will be really hard to fix, let alone even diagnose.

Comment: Sounds bad, how do you reset to a valid state?

Comment: Do you use git, gh, svn? rcs? cvs? anything? Otherwise, the most you can do is look at your eclipse log and retrace what is failing. Something in your project setup is causing Eclipse to fail while trying to render some things. Have you also tried openning eclipse in clean mode? via a terminal `eclipse -clean`

Comment: And what i can't understand is the app will run on the emulator!

Comment: these are 2 different issues. Eclipse is unable to read the project correctly, nothing says the source is incorrect. Your IDE is just misconfigured/in-a-bad-state. Fixing it is again hard. Might be easier to just delete the eclipse project (without deleting contents) then recreate it.

Comment: deleted the project, then recreated it by importing all the original files, same issue, does this mean the project is lost? Think ill have a heart attack now

Comment: it's probably salvageable but you have to look through the eclipse projects. But this is why you use some sort of VCS for projects.

Comment: i havnet used eclipse before and do not see any options for accessing eclipse log in the ADT.....and lastly how do u set up a VCS? Very new to this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing a clean and refresh on eclipse (in terminal CD to Eclipse.app\Contents\MacOS then ./eclipse -clean -refresh. ) removed the error temporarily . Once I updated to eclipse Juno the error disappeared altogether. Hope this helps anyone with similar issue.